# What is the meaning of 磨练?

Tags: translation, meaning, usage

When researching online, finding an exact definition was hard.

Does it mean to make oneself hard? Or like to harden yourself?

Could you give me a few examples?

Comment: Train a person in a tough way, I think Google will work for such commonly used words. Maybe you need a Chinese-Chinese dictionary.

Comment: bkrs to temper oneself
to steel oneself
self-discipline
endurance

put oneself through the mill; temper oneself; steel oneself:
经受艰难困苦的磨练 go through trails and tribulations
磨练人才 cultivate talents
在艰苦的斗争中磨练自己 temper (steel) oneself in a hard struggle

Answer (score 2):

> 磨练： temper oneself hard

在身为罗马奴隶的艰苦磨练中，宾汉变得更强壮、更有耐力。

Ben-Hur's years of enduring hardship as a Roman slave strengthened him and increased his endurance.

唯有艰苦磨练才能强化心灵

only through experiences of trial and suffering can the soul be strengthened

Sometimes, you might see 磨炼(smelt) instead of 磨练(exercise/training). There are some disputation on which one is correct. But main idea is that 磨炼 is sort of wrong words, but you may understand it as a synonym.

Answer (score 1):

> 磨练 / mó liàn /

1

put oneself through the mill; temper oneself; steel oneself:

go through trails and tribulations;

经受艰难困苦的磨练

cultivate talents;

磨练人才

A side note: You should have a Chinese dictionary handy. I've seen some folks in this site use Pleco.

Answer (score 0):

磨練

1. **to hone** / to temper/ to steel (one's skill set, temperament or condition.)

Examples:

磨練球技 - to hone one's football skill

磨練刀法 - to hone one's knife skill

磨練身心 - to temper/ steel one's body and mind

2. endurance (n)

Examples:

一個磨練 - an endurance

一個艱苦的磨練 - a tough endurance

~~~~~~~~~~~~~

鍛練(to forge) is a term similar to 磨練(to hone)

Examples:

鍛練身體 (to temper/forge one's body) ;

鍛練技巧 (to temper/forge one's skill set)

磨練技巧 (to hone one's skill)

一個鍛練 - a workout

> 磨練
>
> [Google](https://translate.google.com/#zh-CN/en/%E7%A3%A8%E7%B7%B4): hone
>
> [CantoDict](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/words/23314/): grin and bear it; practice hard; self-discipline
>
> [Linguee](https://www.linguee.com/chinese-english/translation/%E7%A3%A8%E7%B7%B4.html): hone ; temper oneself / endurance (n)

Answer (score 0):

Difficult word to pin down, depends on what you wish to express.

艰苦可磨练个性。
Hard work builds character.

磨练: build

生活的磨练早已使他愤世嫉俗.
Experience had embittered his heart against the world.

生活的磨练: experience

可以预料, 那将是非常艰苦的磨练.
I expect it to be quite an ordeal.

艰苦的磨练：quite an ordeal